# why the value of productsCenter variable is null?

Tags: javascript

i want to know wher the error came from, i'm trying to make an ecommerce project with vanilla javaScript, when i start display the products, json data is fetched correctly as a first step, but when i excecuted displayProducts() function it didn't work!

**the error message i got:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.**

i tried console.log(document.querySelector("products-center")) but the result was null, i also made sure that the js script tag is after html tags.

```js
const productsCenter = document.querySelector("products-center");

class Displayproducts {
      async getData() {
            try {
                  let response = await fetch("products.json");
                  let data = await response.json();
                  let products = data.items;
                  let mapped = products.map((el) => {
                        const { title, price } = el.fields;
                        const image = el.fields.image.fields.file.url;
                        const id = el.sys.id;
                        return { title, price, image, id };
                  });
                  return mapped;
            } catch (err) {
                  console.log(err);
            }
      }
}
class UI {
      displayProducts(products) {
            products.forEach((product) => {
                  productsCenter.innerHTML = `<article class="product">
                                          <div class="img-container">
                                                <img
                                                      src="${product.image}"
                                                      alt="product"
                                                      class="product-img"
      
      
                                                />
                                                <button class="bag-btn">
                                                      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                                                       add to bag
                                                </button>
                                          </div>
                                          <h3>${product.title}</h3>
                                          <h4>${product.price}</h4>
                                    </article>`;
            });
      }
}
window.onload = () => {
      const product = new Displayproducts();
      const ui = new UI();
      product.getData().then((products) => {
            ui.displayProducts(products);
      });
};
```

```html
<body>
            <!-- start of nav bar -->
            <nav class="navbar">
                  <div class="navbar-center">
                        <span class="nav-icon">
                              <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                        </span>
                        <!-- <img
                              src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/dd/79/2d/dd792d5596291f410cb8e7ce10a7e91a.png"
                              alt="logo"
                        /> -->
                        <div class="cart-btn"></div>
                        <span class="nav-icon">
                              <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="cart-items">0</div>
                  </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- end of nav bar -->
            <!-- start of header -->
            <header class="hero">
                  <div class="banner">
                        <h1 class="banner-title">furniture collection</h1>
                        <button class="banner-btn">shop now</button>
                  </div>
            </header>
            <!-- end of header -->
            <!-- start of cart -->
            <div class="cart-overlay">
                  <div class="cart">
                        <span class="close-cart">
                              <i class="fas fa-window-close"></i>
                        </span>
                        <h2>your cart</h2>
                        <div class="content"></div>
                        <!-- start of cart item  -->

                        <!-- end of cart item -->
                  </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of cart -->
            <!-- start of products-->
            <section class="products">
                  <div class="section-title">
                        <h2>our products</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="products-center">
                        
                  </div>
            </section>

            <!-- end of products -->

            <script src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
```

Comment: In your case `"products-center"` is a class name and not a tag name, taht's why you get that Error because the `document.querySelector()` returns `null` if the element doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector("products-center");` searches for a DOM element which tag is named "products-center" (something like: `<products-center></products-center>`). And since this doesn't exist, `productsCenter` doesn't contain any valid DOM, and so you cannot set its `innerHTML`.

I can see `<div class="products-center">` in your HTML, so I guess you meant to use `const productsCenter = document.querySelector(".products-center");` (note the `.`).